# Libgdx Switching Screens and Viewports

Tags: java, libgdx

I am having an issue when switching screens in libgdx. I am building a asteroids game clone. So first my MainMenuScreen class (which uses a Fitviewport) is rendered and then I call setScreen() to GameScreen (GameScreen doesn't use a Fitviewport) and that works except that the second screen renders as if its using a Fitviewport. If I resize the second screen then the whole window is used for rendering. Why is this happening? Here are some pictures:

MainMenuScreen class:

[image: Image 1]

GameScreen class after switching screens, the screen has black bars on the side (I colored the boundary in red for you) which I don't want:

[image: Image 2]

I want the GameScreen to use all the window area for rendering, and not have black bars like the MainMenu. I am not using any Fitviewport in GameScreen also.

Here are relevant parts of my MainMenuScreen class:

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainMenu";
    private static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 400;
    MyGdxGame game;

       ...

    public MainMenuScreen(MyGdxGame game)
    {

        this.game = game;
        viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);

        // Play button listener
        btnPlay.addListener( new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.log(TAG, "PLAY");
              MainMenuScreen.this.game.setScreen(MainMenuScreen.this.game.gameScreen);
            };
        });

             ....
    }
```

Here is my GameScreen class:

```
MyGdxGame game;
OrthographicCamera guiCam;
World world;
WorldRenderer renderer;


public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game, SpriteBatch batch)
{
    this.game = game;
    guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(400, 400);
    guiCam.position.set(400 / 2, 400 / 2, 0);
    world = new World();
    renderer = new WorldRenderer(game, batch, world);
}

public void draw()
{
    GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();
}

@Override
public void show()
{
    world.createLevel();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{

}

@Override
public void pause()
{

}

@Override
public void resume()
{

}

@Override
public void hide()
{

}

@Override
public void dispose()
{

}
```

Comment: what kind of viewport are you using then in GameScreen?

Comment: I am not using any viewport just a orthographicCamera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        viewport.update(width, height, true);

    }
```

Whenever you update the viewport, you are also updating the underlying opengl viewport and this causes the black bars to persist to the second screen (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). Thus if you want to reset it back to normal you must use the following line of code in your second screen show() method (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d):

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Comment: I had close to the same issue. Start screen would be "full" screen then when you went to play screen had black borders and if you went back to start screen from play screen black borders would be present. adding: Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); to the render method fixed it